# Rails 3 Links are broken after activescaffold update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold, broken-links

I just updated active scaffold on my rails app, and now all the links are broken on the site.  If I hover over the link in firefox, I can see `http://localhost:3000/correct_link`; however, when I click the link, I end up at `http://localhost:3000/current_link#__1_`.  When the link is loaded all styling/javascript is messed up.  Furthermore, the number after the two underscores increases every time I click another link, but I can never navigate away from `http://localhost:3000/current_link__NUM_`.

Interestingly, if I type the url that I want into the browser, all is well.  There don't seem to be any errors in my logs or in my server console.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  The error was caused by my removing active_scaffold, which introduced some weird behavior from custom javascript that had hooked into it.  After active scaffold was removed, the javascript started hijacking the links.  Shuffling the javascript around fixed the bug